# Ubuntu 17.10 how to install Nvidia GEFORCE GT 740M

Tags: nvidia, 17.10, nvidia-geforce

I have been able to use nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 17.04 but unable to install the driver using `sudo apt install nvidia-375 nvidia-prime` in Ubuntu 17.10

Or is there any other way to make it works?

Comment: Why are you installing that version specifically?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I will try to click on `software updates` and click `additional driver` tab to install the driver.

In my previous experiences, it mostly worked...